# Imported Content Doesnt Show Up On Frontend

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, query-posts, import, bulk-import

I found similar problems posted couple times, for different custom post types, but none of the solutions worked for me and these, other questions, didnt have much info provided, I'll try to give as detailed info as its possible and hopefully, this thread will help many others in my situation.

**Problem:** I exported custom post type content from WordPress, and imported it into another WordPress.

Content is there in the Database and in Backend, however, nothing shows up on the frontend. If I go to edit window in backend and just click on "update" button, after that, that specific post does show up on the frontend.

This is a big problem when you have LOTS of posts :))

What Does **NOT** work:

1. Mass Edit on the list page in backend doesnt work, even if I
   change author, or category.
2. Simply, QUICK EDIT from list page in backend doesnt help, I need to
   go inside the post and click on update button there to make post
   visible on frontend.
3. I did update some custom meta field values for specific post in
   Database, to see if it would show up on frontend... - It didnt!
4. On this particular situation, I used default wordpress export and
   import, however, Ive had the same problem previously with WP ALL
   IMPORT plugin, but at that time it was no more than 20 posts (20
   woocommerce products in that particular case) and I just went inside
   the edit page of each product and updated manually.
5. I compared data for specific post in postmeta table before and after
   I went into the edit page and clicked on button - No changes at all.
   Table is exactly same, so I cant replicate what was changed in
   postmeta table for that specific post, what made it visible on
   frontend.
6. Changing of Permalinks, or Updating Permalinks doesnt help.
7. Post is visible (even without clicking the "update" button) if I
   click on VIEW post from backend, It takes me to single post page and
   all data is there, but the post category / listing doesnt show
   anything unless I click on update button in backend.

Strange thing is, I dont need to change anything at all. All I need to do is get into the edit page and click on update button.

Below is the code / query I use to display list of posts.

```
<?php
$featured_companies_query_args = array(
    'post_type' => array( 'company_reviews' ),
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'status'    => 'publish',
    'orderby'   => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
$featured_companies = new WP_Query( $featured_companies_query_args );
?>
```

and then comes the loop that does the layout, titles etc... Its working fine. I just gave the query as an example, maybe I could modify it somehow to show all posts without manually updating them, I dont know, Ive lost almost whole day on this now, hope you guys can help me :))

Thank you

Comment: How is the custom post type registered?

Comment: Do the imported posts have a post status of 'publish'? That could explain why they are not showing on the front end.

Comment: @s_ha_dum  Custom post type is registered via custom plugin. But as I mentioned above, it has also happened on woocommerce, and also has happened to many other users on different plugins, so I dont think its the problem with the way custom post types are registered.

Comment: @JMB   Of course the status is publish :))

Comment: How are you exporting and importing this data? Is the custom plugin installed on the destination WordPress site?

Comment: You can never be too careful. Sometimes the answer lies in the simple stuff.